# Special jQuery Accordion Issue

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have an issue with getting this accordion style element to work correctly. The issue is i have a solid blue button nested which is the toggle for opening and closing the extras panel, currently nothing is opening.

What i am trying to do is when you open one of the elements and you click on another then previous one will close, so you can only one open at a time.

```js
$(".btn-toggle").on("click", function() {

  if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
    $(this).siblings(".wip-project-extras-wrapper").slideUp(200);
    $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-angle-down').addClass('fa-angle-left');
  } else {
    $('.wip-base-plate-wrapper > .wip-project-info-wrapper').find('i').removeClass('fa-angle-down').addClass('fa-angle-left');
    $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-angle-left').addClass('fa-angle-down');
    $('.wip-base-plate-wrapper > .wip-project-info-wrapper').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".wip-project-extras-wrapper").slideUp(200);
    $(this).siblings(".wip-project-extras-wrapper").slideDown(200);
  }
});
```

```css
.wip-base-plate-wrapper {
    padding: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.10);
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.wip-base-plate-wrapper .wip-project-info-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
}
.wip-base-plate-wrapper .wip-project-info-wrapper .wip-project-number,
.wip-base-plate-wrapper .wip-project-info-wrapper .wip-project-name 
{
    font-family: ITCAvantGardeStd-Demi;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #002C76;
}
.wip-base-plate-wrapper .wip-project-info-wrapper .wip-project-number {
    padding-right: 20px;
    border-right: 1px solid #4891DC;
}
.wip-base-plate-wrapper .wip-project-info-wrapper .wip-project-name 
{
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.wip-base-plate-wrapper .wip-project-info-wrapper .wip-project-actions {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}
.wip-base-plate-wrapper .wip-project-info-wrapper .wip-project- actions ul {
    list-style: none;
}
.wip-base-plate-wrapper .wip-project-info-wrapper .wip-project-actions ul li {
    display: inline-flex;
    margin-right: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.wip-base-plate-wrapper .wip-project-info-wrapper .wip-project-actions ul li:last-child {
    margin-right:0px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #002C76;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.wip-base-plate-wrapper .wip-project-info-wrapper .wip-project-actions ul li:last-child i {
    padding: 6px 7px;
}
.wip-base-plate-wrapper .wip-project-info-wrapper .wip-project-actions ul li i {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
}
.wip-base-plate-wrapper .wip-project-info-wrapper .wip-project-actions ul li a i {
    color: #002C76;
}
.wip-base-plate-wrapper .wip-project-info-wrapper .wip-project-actions ul li a:hover i {
    color: #002C76;
    background-color: rgba(72, 145, 220, 0.5);
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.wip-base-plate-wrapper .wip-project-extras-wrapper {
    padding-left: 100px;
    display: none;
}
.wip-base-plate-wrapper .wip-project-extras-wrapper ul {
    list-style: none;
    columns: 3;
}
.wip-base-plate-wrapper .wip-project-extras-wrapper ul li {

}
.wip-base-plate-wrapper .wip-project-extras-wrapper ul li span.title 
{
    display: inline-flex;
    font-family: ITCAvantGardeStd-Md;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #4A4A4A;
    width: 115px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.wip-base-plate-wrapper .wip-project-extras-wrapper ul li span.data 
{
    font-family: ITCAvantGardeStd-Demi;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #4891DC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wip-base-plate-wrapper">
    <div class="wip-project-info-wrapper">
      <div class="wip-project-number">2344321</div>
      <div class="wip-project-name">Fancy Title</div>
      <div class="wip-project-actions">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/summary/1234"><i class="far fa-chart-bar" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="View Summary"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="/details/2134"><i class="far fa-pencil-alt" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="View"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="/archive/1234"><i class="far fa-archive" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Archive"></i></a></li>
          <li class="btn-toggle"><i class="far fa-angle-left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Extras"></i></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wip-project-extras-wrapper">
      [extra content to view]
    </div>
  </div>
  ... repeat above
</div>
```

-->>> [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/james182/Lc31jo70/) <<<

Comment: I've added a Stack Snippet to your question. If you can [edit] that and add your CSS, the question would have jsFiddle-like functionality right here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Has any one got any suggestions as to how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Is solved the problem after breaking it down i figured out my issue. Here is the updated JS for reference.

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-toggle",function () 
    {
        // Default close all panels
        $(".wip-project-extras-wrapper").slideUp();

        if( $(this).hasClass("active") ){
            // close + resets all
            $(this).removeClass("active");
            $(this).siblings(".wip-project-extras-wrapper").slideUp(200);
            $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-angle-down').addClass('fa-angle-left');
        }
        else
        {
            // Try and close all previous panels + reset toggle
            $('.wip-base-plate-wrapper > .wip-project-info-wrapper').find('i').removeClass('fa-angle-down').addClass('fa-angle-left');
            $(this).removeClass("active");
            $('.wip-base-plate-wrapper > .wip-project-info-wrapper').find('li').removeClass("active");
            $(".wip-project-extras-wrapper").slideUp(200); // Close 

            // Then open selected panel
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-angle-left').addClass('fa-angle-down');
            
            $(this).parents().eq(2).siblings(".wip-project-extras-wrapper").slideDown(200);

        }
    });
```